# Is it possible to access the VSTS data storage from outside of VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

I use the code below to access the data storage in my VSTS extension.

```
// Get data service
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
    // Get all document under the collection
    dataService.getDocuments("MyCollection").then(function(docs) {
        console.log("There are " + docs.length + " in the collection.");
    });
});
```

Is it possible to use this in a general web app that does not use VSTS?
I just want to access the data stored in a different web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a call to this URL should work:

```
https://{yourvstsaccount}.extmgmt.visualstudio.com/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{extensionpublisherName}/{extensionname}/Data/Scopes/{scope}/Collections/{collectionName}/Documents/{documentName}
```

For exmaple:
[image]

Comment: What does the `extensionname` has to be? There are several settings that I made in the `vss-extension.json`. I have `id`, `name`, `id` in the `contributions` array. I assume that it is the `name`, but what do i have to put if there is a space in my name? Also, what does the `documentName` have to be? I only set the collection name when I setup the data storage.

Comment: Sorry, It's the id of the extension.

Comment: If you didn't pass the document name when create, it should create one automatically. Did you check that?

Comment: It's keep giving me 401 unauthorized. I am using my microsoft account (email address) for the Authorization and my VSTS organization name for `{yourvstsaccount}`. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Dawn17 You have to use personal access token or enable alternative credential.

Comment: Chen, Which auth method do we have to use if we want to use personal access token? Also, is the access token the one what we can make on out VSTS personal settings page?

Comment: @Dawn17 Basic Auth, yes, the personal access token under personal settings\security.

Comment: But basic auth asks you for username and password, not personal access token.

Comment: @Dawn17 The username is anystring and the password is the personal access token.

Comment: Any string? So, we can just put literally anything and the password is the only thing that matters?

Comment: Great. It changed from `401 unauthorized` to `404 not found` which means the authentication worked. `https://{orgname}.visualstudio.com/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extensionID}/Data/Scopes/User/Collections/{collectionName}/Documents` Is the api that I used but it's not found. Is there a simpler API that I can use to test if it actually works? Also, I am still not sure where to find the `{documentName}`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dawn17 You missed "extmgmt" string after the orgname in the URL. For the documentname (the id of the document), refer to this link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts#create-a-document

Comment: Are there some simpler API that I can use to test?

Comment: @Dawn17 No, but if you have created an extension to create and read the data storage, press F12 of your brower and switch to network tab. and then refresh the page that host your extension, you should see the detailed url to your document.